# Can not start Cloudera Manger Server, because of RuntimeException: Upgrade not allowed from CM3.x

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I had trouble installing Cloudera Manager(ver 5.8.3).

I installed cloudera-manager-agent-5.8.3-1.cm583.p0.8.el6.x86_64, 
cloudera-manager-server-5.8.3-1.cm583.p0.8.el6.x86_64,
cloudera-manager-daemons-5.8.3-1.cm583.p0.8.el6.x86_64 on CentOS 6.5 64bit
 -> using $rpm -Uvh [packagename]

and installed mysql and set conf file(/etc/cloudera-manager-server/db.properties)

but i contacted error message...

I don't know that why occured a message about CM3...

I just install a cloudera-manager 5.8.3 and this version not contains CM3...

How can i solve this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cloudera.server.cmf.TrialState': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactoryBean' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Upgrade not allowed from CM3.x.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.Main.bootstrapSpringContext(Main.java:387)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.Main.<init>(Main.java:242)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.Main.main(Main.java:216)Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Upgrade not allowed from CM3.x.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 17 moreCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Upgrade not allowed from CM3.x.
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.bootstrap.EntityManagerFactoryBean.CM3Fail(EntityManagerFactoryBean.java:326)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.bootstrap.EntityManagerFactoryBean.checkVersionDoFail(EntityManagerFactoryBean.java:273)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.bootstrap.EntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject(EntityManagerFactoryBean.java:126)
    at com.cloudera.server.cmf.bootstrap.EntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject(EntityManagerFactoryBean.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Looks like Cloudera was picking some older version details from somehwhere on the host (may be someone used CM3 there).

I also could not find the exact reason but bouncing mysql server and resetting all helped me

```
/usr/share/cmf/schema/scm_prepare_database.sh mysql cm_db root yourpassword
```